# Use color and variables in read command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to have a colored prompt in bash.
Usually, I do this like this, for example:

```
read -p $'\033[1;32m hello world?' helloWorld
```

This works fine, but no variables are expanded in the prompt string. Now I want color and expanded variables, but this does not work:

```
read -p $'\033[1;32m hello $thisVariableIsNotExpanded ?' helloWorld
```

I tried just using `echo -e` instead of `read -p`, but this adds a linebreak which I do not want.

So, how can I have colors and variable expansion in a read prompt?

Comment: Put your colour codes into variables, it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes so that the variable gets expanded:

```
read -p $'\033[1;32m hello '"$thisVariableIsNotExpanded"'?' 
#                           ^                          ^
```

See it in action:

```
$ thisVariableIsNotExpanded="gexicide"
$ read -p $'\033[1;32m hello '"$thisVariableIsNotExpanded"'?' helloWorld
 hello gexicide?
# ^
# this is green
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use `tput` exactly once to obtain the escape codes (it's a bad idea to use terminal-specific literals for the escape codes - not all terminals use the same codes).  Then just use ordinary double quotes, and interpolate your variables in the usual way.

```
bold="`tput bold`"
fg_green="`tput setaf 2`"
sgr0="``tput sgr0``"

read -p "${bold}${green}hello $thisVariableIsExpanded ?${sgr0}' helloWorld
```

Beware - if you're setting a foreground colour for your text, have you thought about what the background colour might be?  Green against red is hard to read, and green against green impossible...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo -n` and then read:

```
echo -ne "\033[1;32m hello $thisVariableIsNotExpanded ?"
```

Or you can use a variable to build the prompt:

```
START=$'\033[1;32m hello '
OTHER="${START}$thisVariableIsNotExpanded ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but `echo -ne` will interpret color codes without adding a linebreak.